# Finding coordinates of the final character in a text texture when rendering in SDL2, C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2

In SDL2, i am trying to encase text inside of a textbox. For me to do this, I wan't to create a boolean function that only allows the user to add text to it provided it has not reached the end of the textbox. This should require its width of the textbox and the text size of the text, however I can't find any help on how to register if it has reached the end of it as each letter and number is a different width. The best way i can think of is finding the x location of the final character of the text string, however I don't know how to do it as SDL2's font/render/texture/surface for text requires the initial position to render a text, what i have tried so far is multiplying the length of the string by the text size and checking if it is less than the width of the textbox's width, but that falls short mostly, however on some characters it doesn't. It seems it is not a linear thing to create a formula for how far from its initial X point it began. An other possibility is finding each individual characters width from its textsize but i don't know how to do that either.

Comment: Multiplying glyph width by character count only works for monospace fonts. There are `TTF_SizeText`/`TTF_SizeUTF8` to get size of resulting rendered text, or `TTF_GlyphMetrics` to query info about one glyph.

Comment: If I use Ariel.ttf for my text rendering what would I have to write to, let’s say find the width of the word “hello”, would I iterate through it and add up the width of each letter? That works but to find the individual size of each lettter how would I do it (individual width)

Comment: You can pass entire "hello" and it'll tell you what size it'll take if you render this text. For individual glyphs check https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_38.html I think you're interested in `advance` metric. Or you can pass single letter to `TTF_SizeText`.

Comment: Ah, very nice, thank you!